# What does a prime (apostrophe) mean before a predicate?

Tags: logic, notation, higher-order-logic

I found this statement in [a paper by John McCarthy](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/applications.pdf):

$$
\forall x.ostrich\ x \supset  species\ x ={}^\prime{}ostrich
$$

I can't figure out what the prime indicates.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it is used as an "operator" for [nominalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization), in place of the standard $\lambda$ operator.

See :

- Nino Cocchiarella, [Conceptual Realism and the Nexus of Predication : Lecture Five](http://www.stoqnet.org/materials/cocch_rome5.pdf) (Rome, 2004), page 14 :

> Consider, for example, the predicate phrase "is famous", which can be symbolized as a $\lambda$-abstract $[\lambda xFamous(x)]$ as well as simply by $Famous( )$. The $\lambda$-abstract is preferable as a way of representing the infinitive "to be famous", which is one form of *nominalization*:
>
> > to be famous $\to$ to be an $x$ such that $x$ is famous $\to$ $[\lambda xFamous(x)]$.

The $\lambda$-abstract  $[\lambda xFamous(x)]$ acts as a *term*, and thus can fill the argument-place of a predicate (like : $x = t$).

Comment: That seems to be make sense to me. So would it make sense in this context to interpret the sentence as: for every x if x is an ostrich then the species of x is "being an ostrich" (where "being an ostrich" is representing the property of being an ostrich, as a term)?

Comment: @robguinness -. Yes, or  the species of x is "to be an ostrich".

Answer (score 1):

An apostrophe before the name of a predicate has no standard meaning. I believe McCarthy is just using it as a systematic way for assigning symbolic identifiers to classes, so that he can economise on axioms. I.e., if instead of saying $ostrich(x)$ you say $species(x) = 452$ and instead of saying $penguin(x)$ you say $species(x) = 453$, then you avoid the possibility of having an $x$ that satisfies $ostrich(x) \land penguin(x)$. $'ostrich$ and $'penguin$ are McCarthy's convention for naming the symbolic identifiers, rather than using specific identifiers like $452$ and $453$.